# Why does this line produce an error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras, mnist

I'm completely new to keras and to get started, I'm trying to follow [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/) tutorial. I use theano backend.
Sadly, I already encounter a difficulty at this line:

```
model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, init='normal', activation='relu'))
```

It says:

> UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(784, input_dim=784, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal")`
>     '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature)
>
> INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Refreshing lock [...]

An error is thrown as well:
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL)
initialization routine failed.

**What am I doing wrong? Every idea is greatly appreciated :D**

Here is the complete error traceback (partly German):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-12b29e43ecfe> in <module>()
----> 1 model = baseline_model()
      2 
      3 model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), nb_epoch=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2)
      4 
      5 scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

<ipython-input-57-16bc1d352f3b> in baseline_model()
      2     model = Sequential() #RNN?
      3     #InputLayer
----> 4     model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, init='normal', activation='relu'))
      5     #OutputLayer
      6     model.add(Dense(num_classes, init='normal', activation='softmax'))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in add(self, layer)
    420                 # and create the node connecting the current layer
    421                 # to the input layer we just created.
--> 422                 layer(x)
    423 
    424             if len(layer.inbound_nodes) != 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    526                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
    527                 if len(input_shapes) == 1:
--> 528                     self.build(input_shapes[0])
    529                 else:
    530                     self.build(input_shapes)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in build(self, input_shape)
    825                                       name='kernel',
    826                                       regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
--> 827                                       constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    828         if self.use_bias:
    829             self.bias = self.add_weight((self.units,),

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in add_weight(self, shape, initializer, name, trainable, regularizer, constraint)
    362         """
    363         initializer = initializers.get(initializer)
--> 364         weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=K.floatx(), name=name)
    365         if regularizer is not None:
    366             self.add_loss(regularizer(weight))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype)
     71     def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
     72         return K.random_normal(shape, self.mean, self.stddev,
---> 73                                dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
     74 
     75     def get_config(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py in random_normal(shape, mean, stddev, dtype, seed)
   1935         seed = np.random.randint(1, 10e6)
   1936     rng = RandomStreams(seed=seed)
-> 1937     return rng.normal(size=shape, avg=mean, std=stddev, dtype=dtype)
   1938 
   1939 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py in normal(self, size, avg, std, ndim, dtype, nstreams)
   1572             n_samples = prod(size) + (prod(size) % 2)
   1573         flattened = self.uniform(size=(n_samples,), dtype=dtype,
-> 1574                                  nstreams=nstreams)
   1575 
   1576         if constant:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py in uniform(self, size, low, high, ndim, dtype, nstreams)
   1352         if nstreams is None:
   1353             nstreams = self.n_streams(size)
-> 1354         rstates = self.get_substream_rstates(nstreams, dtype)
   1355 
   1356         if self.use_cuda and dtype == 'float32':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py in res(*args, **kwargs)
    115         def res(*args, **kwargs):
    116             with self:
--> 117                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
    118         return res
    119 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py in get_substream_rstates(self, n_streams, dtype, inc_rstate)
   1254         # If multMatVect.dot_modulo isn't compiled, compile it.
   1255         if multMatVect.dot_modulo is None:
-> 1256             multMatVect(rval[0], A1p72, M1, A2p72, M2)
   1257 
   1258         # This way of calling the Theano fct is done to bypass Theano overhead.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py in multMatVect(v, A, m1, B, m2)
     64         o = DotModulo()(A_sym, s_sym, m_sym, A2_sym, s2_sym, m2_sym)
     65         multMatVect.dot_modulo = function(
---> 66             [A_sym, s_sym, m_sym, A2_sym, s2_sym, m2_sym], o, profile=False)
     67 
     68     # This way of calling the Theano fct is done to bypass Theano overhead.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py in function(inputs, outputs, mode, updates, givens, no_default_updates, accept_inplace, name, rebuild_strict, allow_input_downcast, profile, on_unused_input)
    324                    on_unused_input=on_unused_input,
    325                    profile=profile,
--> 326                    output_keys=output_keys)
    327     # We need to add the flag check_aliased inputs if we have any mutable or
    328     # borrowed used defined inputs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py in pfunc(params, outputs, mode, updates, givens, no_default_updates, accept_inplace, name, rebuild_strict, allow_input_downcast, profile, on_unused_input, output_keys)
    484                          accept_inplace=accept_inplace, name=name,
    485                          profile=profile, on_unused_input=on_unused_input,
--> 486                          output_keys=output_keys)
    487 
    488 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in orig_function(inputs, outputs, mode, accept_inplace, name, profile, on_unused_input, output_keys)
   1794                    on_unused_input=on_unused_input,
   1795                    output_keys=output_keys).create(
-> 1796             defaults)
   1797 
   1798     t2 = time.time()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in create(self, input_storage, trustme, storage_map)
   1660             theano.config.traceback.limit = theano.config.traceback.compile_limit
   1661             _fn, _i, _o = self.linker.make_thunk(
-> 1662                 input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
   1663         finally:
   1664             theano.config.traceback.limit = limit_orig

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py in make_thunk(self, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map)
    697         return self.make_all(input_storage=input_storage,
    698                              output_storage=output_storage,
--> 699                              storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
    700 
    701     def make_all(self, input_storage, output_storage):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py in make_all(self, profiler, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map)
   1045                                                  compute_map,
   1046                                                  no_recycling,
-> 1047                                                  impl=impl))
   1048                 linker_make_thunk_time[node] = time.time() - thunk_start
   1049                 if not hasattr(thunks[-1], 'lazy'):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py in make_thunk(self, node, storage_map, compute_map, no_recycling, impl)
    933             try:
    934                 return self.make_c_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map,
--> 935                                          no_recycling)
    936             except (NotImplementedError, utils.MethodNotDefined):
    937                 # We requested the c code, so don't catch the error.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py in make_c_thunk(self, node, storage_map, compute_map, no_recycling)
    837         _logger.debug('Trying CLinker.make_thunk')
    838         outputs = cl.make_thunk(input_storage=node_input_storage,
--> 839                                 output_storage=node_output_storage)
    840         fill_storage, node_input_filters, node_output_filters = outputs
    841 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py in make_thunk(self, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1188         cthunk, in_storage, out_storage, error_storage = self.__compile__(
   1189             input_storage, output_storage, storage_map,
-> 1190             keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1191 
   1192         res = _CThunk(cthunk, init_tasks, tasks, error_storage)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py in __compile__(self, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1129                                     output_storage,
   1130                                     storage_map,
-> 1131                                     keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1132         return (thunk,
   1133                 [link.Container(input, storage) for input, storage in

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py in cthunk_factory(self, error_storage, in_storage, out_storage, storage_map, keep_lock)
   1584                 node.op.prepare_node(node, storage_map, None, 'c')
   1585             module = get_module_cache().module_from_key(
-> 1586                 key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
   1587 
   1588         vars = self.inputs + self.outputs + self.orphans

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py in module_from_key(self, key, lnk, keep_lock)
   1157             try:
   1158                 location = dlimport_workdir(self.dirname)
-> 1159                 module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
   1160                 name = module.__file__
   1161                 assert name.startswith(location)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py in compile_cmodule(self, location)
   1487                 lib_dirs=self.lib_dirs(),
   1488                 libs=libs,
-> 1489                 preargs=preargs)
   1490         except Exception as e:
   1491             e.args += (str(self.fgraph),)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py in compile_str(module_name, src_code, location, include_dirs, lib_dirs, libs, preargs, py_module, hide_symbols)
   2345             open(os.path.join(location, "__init__.py"), 'w').close()
   2346             assert os.path.isfile(lib_filename)
-> 2347             return dlimport(lib_filename)
   2348 
   2349 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py in dlimport(fullpath, suffix)
    300             warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",
    301                                     message="numpy.ndarray size changed")
--> 302             rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
    303         t1 = time.time()
    304         import_time += t1 - t0

ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.
```

Comment: It seems only a **warning** to me, not an **error** as such. Code should work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this: Afterwards, it throws an ImportError at this line

Comment: Then include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: It is just a dive through theano and keras. I doubt, that it would be helpful.

Comment: Without the complete error traceback, my first comment is all you will get, since that is the only info we can see.

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: This is not a keras error. I suspect your are using python3 with theano. There seems to be some issues with p3 and theano. See this issue for details: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3376

Comment: Your DLL is missing. Use a Dependency walker and check out which DLL is missing and install the same. It will work fine then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply doing a complete reinstallation. Perhaps, there was something messed up with the old one.
For Windows users I strongly recommend this tutorial: http://efavdb.com/gpu-accelerated-theano-keras-with-windows-10/